# HashTable implementation with ZERO collisions for a set ? Food for thought?

Tags: c++

Consider a hash table with an array size of N=1500 slots. The hash table stores 1400 integers from the range [1000000, 1001500]. Give a hash function which guarantees that no collisions occur?

I don't get this , how can you do this if the elements are non-distinct ? If they're distinct then yeah HashKey = integer and you're done with this ?

Comment: It's called a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

Comment: Hm, there are 1500 slots, but the given range is 1501 large (from 1000000 to 1001500 inclusive). Perfect hash is not possible.

Comment: @Dialecticus Only 1400 of the possible 1501 are used, so it should be possible.

Comment: @MarkB I wonder what would that magical hash function look like. It still must accept only one parameter, and not have any internal states. In order to reduce 1501 domain to 1500 domain some collision must exist.

Comment: @Dialecticus Ow, I misread that. Indeed, 1501, that renders my answer kind of invalid, in case the stated problem doesn’t have an error in it. On the other hand, you’re right and it needs a collision, except if you put in the knowledge about only inserting 1400 elements. [ I deleted my answer for the time being ]

Answer (score 0):

As stated, I don't believe you can solve this problem. You have 1501 possible candidate items to fit into 1500 buckets, so unless you know something about the input set you can't decidedly create a hash for it.

If however you know ahead of time even one specific item that won't exist among the 1400 the problem becomes trivial.

```
template <int MISSING_ITEM>
int hash(int input)
{
    if(MISSING_ITEM != 1001500 && input == 1001500)
    {
        input = MISSING_ITEM;
    }

    return input - 1000000
}
```